# powershell files and subfolder files renaming

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to powershell and have now read too many examples and fried my brain with Get-ChildItem examples.

I have a folder structure for my films as follows

```
Films
├─Film1
| Film1Name.mp4
│ └─Subs
│   └─English.SRT
│
├─Film2
| Film2Name.mp4
│ └─Subs
│   └─English.SRT
|
├─Film3
| Film3Name.mp4
│ └─Subs
│   └─English.SRT
```

What I am trying to achieve is to rename and move the *.srt file up a folder level and rename to either the filename of the film or the folder name of the film and insert .ENG to the .SRT filename before the extension.
Then delete the unused 'Subs' folder, and do this recursively.

Ending up with the following based on the filename

```
├─Film1
| Film1Name.mp4
│ Film1Name.ENG.SRT
```

or this based on the folder name

```
├─Film1
| Film1.mp4
│ Film1.ENG.SRT
```

Any help would be most appreciated, either method would work

I was playing with this code from someone elses post and wiped out my test folder

```
$rootPath = "c:\Test"

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Directory | ForEach-Object {
 
    $targetFolder = $_.FullName
    Resolve-Path "$targetFolder\*" | ForEach-Object {
        Move-Item -Path "$_\*.SRT" -Destination $targetFolder -Force
        Remove-Item -Path $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a try

Comment: Using this just made my folders contain a file called ".ENG.SRT" and removed all other files and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to get a list of all the top level directories which are named after your "films" after setting the root directory.

```bsh
Set-Location -Path "Your directory path here"
$Films = Get-ChildItem -Directory
```

Once we've done that we an iterate through each one, push the location to that directory and check for the existence of a folder called "Subs". `Pop-Location` returns us back to the previous location after doing what we need to do.

```bsh
foreach ($Film in $Films) {
    Push-Location $Film
    if ((Get-ChildItem -Directory).Name -contains "Subs") {
        # Do stuff
    }
    Pop-Location
}
```

If we find a "Subs" directory, we want to check for the existence of an ".SRT" files. We may have subtitles for multiple languages.

```bsh
$Subs = Get-ChildItem -Path *.srt -Recurse
```

Check if `$Subs` is not null.

```bsh
if ($null -ne $Subs) { }
```

Move any ".SRT" files to the current location and rename them as specified.

```bsh
foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
    $FilmPath = $Film.Fullname
    $FilmName = $Film.Name
    $SubtitleLang = $Sub.BaseName.Substring(0,3).ToUpper()
    $Extension = $Sub.Extension
    Move-Item -Path $Sub -Destination "$FilmPath\$FilmName.$SubtitleLang$Extension"
}
```

If you're absolutely sure that you want to remove the "Subs" folder, we will check it's empty first. We can write a message if there are still files remaining instead.

```bsh
$RemainingFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path Subs -Recurse
if ($null -eq $RemainingFiles) {
    Remove-Item -Path Subs -Force
}
else {
    Write-Warning "There are still files in $($Film.FullName)\Subs"
}
```

Putting it all together

```bsh
Set-Location -Path "Your directory path here"
$Films = Get-ChildItem -Directory

# Loop through the Films
foreach ($Film in $Films) {
    Push-Location $Film
    if ((Get-ChildItem -Directory).Name -contains "Subs") {
        # Find any SRT files in the "Subs" directory
        $Subs = Get-ChildItem -Path Subs/*.srt -Recurse
        if ($null -ne $Subs) {
            foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
                $FilmPath = $Film.Fullname
                $FilmName = $Film.Name
                $SubtitleLang = $Sub.BaseName.Substring(0,3).ToUpper()
                $Extension = $Sub.Extension
                Move-Item -Path $Sub -Destination "$FilmPath\$FilmName.$SubtitleLang$Extension"
            }
        }
    }

    # Remove the Subs folder
    $RemainingFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path Subs -Recurse
    if ($null -eq $RemainingFiles) {
        Remove-Item -Path Subs -Force
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "There are still files in $($Film.FullName)\Subs"
    }

    # Return to the root directory for the next folder.
    Pop-Location
}
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for a very well answered, explained and laid out reply.
It is starting to help me understand a bit more.

It is not renaming the .SRT file to "Film1.ENG.SRT", just renaming to "Film1" with no extension.

Also is it possible to rename the film filename to the folder name at the same time with filenames original extension?

Comment: Updated to rename the subtitles too based off the first three letters of the language. For English this will be ENG as specified in your question. Changing the Film file name is an unknown for me if it's not the same name as the folder already.

Comment: You could have named it anything, you may have different media types, there may be more than one media file, etc.

Comment: So many thanks for this, I need to read some powershell books. Getting an error now as below.
There is only going to be one .srt file and might not always start with ENG, so can just change the $SubtitleLang = "ENG"

'Move-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At line:15 char:17
+ ...             Move-Item -Path $Sub -Destination "$Film\$FilmName.$Subti ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Test\Film1\Subs\english.srt:FileInfo) [Move-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException'

Comment: I can't recreate it when setting up a sample test directory with fake files. Going to test on PowerShell Desktop now. Is it failing on one or more items? By the way, you don't need to set the `$SubtitleLang`, if there is only one language it will be creating "ENG" from "English" anyway.

Comment: yes it is failing on all of the test folders.
some of the subtitle files are named 03English.srt,1English, 10_ENGLISH etc, most have numbers at the start of them, depends on the order on the DVD/Bluray.
Should I be running this as a saved .ps1 or through ISE (which is what I am using)

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Windows PowerShell uses the name of the directory rather than the fullname when converting it to string, unlike PowerShell Core. It should work now as I've explicitly specified the fullname of the file. The subtitle thing wasn't specified in the original question. If there isn't a recognisable pattern then that is difficult to deal with. In that case, just set your `$SubtitleLang` to "ENG", but if you have more than one subtitle file in the Subs folder, this will cause errors too.

Comment: Thanks for that, it works, as I said I can rename the filmnames with BRU. So many thanks. Save me a lot of time doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood, you know how many folders (Films) you have then this might work:

```
1..3|ForEach {Copy-Item -Path C:\Films\Film$_\Subs\English.srt -Destination C:\Films\Film$_\Film$_.ENG.SRT} 
1..3|ForEach {Remove-Item -Path C:\Films\Film$_\Subs -Recurse -Force}
```